# How to delete old plot on Matplotlib figure embedded in PyQt5?

Tags: matplotlib

I am using matplotlib figure embedded in pyqt5 to draw a frame taking the height and the width from line edit entries.It works well but when I change the values inside the line edits and click on the push button it will draw another frame over the previous one. I have tried plt.gcf().clear() and ax.clear and they did not work.

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setWindowTitle("Draw Frame")
    self.setGeometry(100,100,680, 450)

    # Creation of figure and canvas
    self.figure = plt.figure()
    self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
    self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
    self.ax.axis("off")
    #self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
    self.plot_widget = QWidget(self)
    self.plot_widget.setGeometry(250, 10, 400, 400)
    plot_box = QVBoxLayout()
    plot_box.addWidget(self.canvas)
    self.plot_widget.setLayout(plot_box)

    self.label1=QLabel("Frame height",self)
    self.label1.move(10,30)
    self.label2 = QLabel("Frame height", self)
    self.label2.move(10, 70)

    self.lineEdit1=QLineEdit(self)
    self.lineEdit1.move(100,30)
    self.lineEdit1.setText("10")
    self.lineEdit2 = QLineEdit(self)
    self.lineEdit2.move(100, 70)
    self.lineEdit2.setText("20")

    self.button = QPushButton('Draw Frame', self)
    self.button.clicked.connect(self.plot)
    self.button.move(70, 350)

    self.show()

def plot(self):
    if len(self.lineEdit1.text())!=0:
        self.h=int(self.lineEdit1.text())
    else:
        self.h=0
    if len(self.lineEdit2.text()) != 0:
        self.w=int(self.lineEdit2.text())
    else:
        self.w=0

    x = [0, 0, self.w, self.w]
    y = [0, self.h, self.h, 0]
    self.ax.plot(x, y)
    self.canvas.draw()
```

[Picture of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xypTS.png)

Comment: it looks like `self.ax.clear()` should work. What is the problem when using it? Can you provide the [mcve] that shows what goes wrong in that case?

Comment: Thank you! That definitely works. But no matter how I change the values, the frame will look the same. the only difference is the divisions of the axes. That is disappointed to me, what I want is the user enters the width and the height and see the frame changing.

Comment: Only the divisions  are changing and not the frame's look? That is probably because of autoscale. You should disable it and set x and y limits yourself if you want the frame to move and the divisions constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of clearing the axes you may update the line that is drawn with the new coordinates.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import sys

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Draw Frame")
        self.setGeometry(100,100,680, 450)

        # Creation of figure and canvas
        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.ax.axis("off")
        self.line, = self.ax.plot([])
        self.ax.axis([0,100,0,100])
        #self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        self.plot_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.plot_widget.setGeometry(250, 10, 400, 400)
        plot_box = QVBoxLayout()
        plot_box.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.plot_widget.setLayout(plot_box)

        self.label1=QLabel("Frame height",self)
        self.label1.move(10,30)
        self.label2 = QLabel("Frame height", self)
        self.label2.move(10, 70)

        self.lineEdit1=QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEdit1.move(100,30)
        self.lineEdit1.setText("10")
        self.lineEdit2 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEdit2.move(100, 70)
        self.lineEdit2.setText("20")

        self.button = QPushButton('Draw Frame', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.plot)
        self.button.move(70, 350)

        self.show()

    def plot(self):
        if len(self.lineEdit1.text())!=0:
            self.h=int(self.lineEdit1.text())
        else:
            self.h=0
        if len(self.lineEdit2.text()) != 0:
            self.w=int(self.lineEdit2.text())
        else:
            self.w=0

        x = [0, 0, self.w, self.w]
        y = [0, self.h, self.h, 0]
        self.line.set_data(x,y)
        self.canvas.draw()

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment above, you need to call self.ax.clear() every time you click the button. Otherwise you will be redrawing on the same plot. Not sure why your graph doesnt reset on clear(), but here is the code I ran which worked fine. Let me know if it works for you:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import sys

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Draw Frame")
        self.setGeometry(100,100,680, 450)

        # Creation of figure and canvas
        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.ax.axis("off")
        #self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        self.plot_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.plot_widget.setGeometry(250, 10, 400, 400)
        plot_box = QVBoxLayout()
        plot_box.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.plot_widget.setLayout(plot_box)

        self.label1=QLabel("Frame height",self)
        self.label1.move(10,30)
        self.label2 = QLabel("Frame height", self)
        self.label2.move(10, 70)

        self.lineEdit1=QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEdit1.move(100,30)
        self.lineEdit1.setText("10")
        self.lineEdit2 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEdit2.move(100, 70)
        self.lineEdit2.setText("20")

        self.button = QPushButton('Draw Frame', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.plot)
        self.button.move(70, 350)

        self.show()

    def plot(self):
        self.ax.clear()
        if len(self.lineEdit1.text())!=0:
            self.h=int(self.lineEdit1.text())
        else:
            self.h=0
        if len(self.lineEdit2.text()) != 0:
            self.w=int(self.lineEdit2.text())
        else:
            self.w=0

        x = [0, 0, self.w, self.w]
        y = [0, self.h, self.h, 0]
        self.ax.plot(x, y)
        self.canvas.draw()

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! Actually, it was working but I wasn't seeing the difference. I noticed that matplotlib does not change the drawings but change the axes divisions when I change the entries in the line edits. it is like keeping a fixed ratio between the width and the height. I would like to see the drawing changing, that not what I expected